Program to optimize cut lengths in C#
I want to write a program which will accept few cut lengths and show the user how to cut 6m steel bar to have as little offcut as possible. I want it to be easy as I'm not advanced in C#.
My code doesn't work as expected. For example in the second cut it should be 3100, 2900 but it shows otherwise.
And the last bar is not needed, don't understand why it appears.
Can you have a look please?
const int BAR_LENGTH = 6000;

List<int> cuts = new(){ 3200,800, 3100, 2900, 1200, 690, 2700, 1200, 1100, 980, 670 };
List<string> cutsOptimized = new();
cuts.Sort();
cuts.Reverse();

int cutSum = 0;
string cutGroup = "";

while (cuts.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cuts.Count; i++)
    {
            if (cutSum + cuts[i] <= BAR_LENGTH)
            {
                cutSum += cuts[i];
                cutGroup += cuts[i].ToString() + ",";
                cuts.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
    }

    cutsOptimized.Add(cutGroup);
    cutGroup = "";
    cutSum = 0;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cutsOptimized));
//result
//3200,2700,
//3100,1200,1100,
//2900,980,690,
//1200,670,
//800,


This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Please note that the correct spelling of "LENGHT" is "LENGTH", both in the question title and the code. It is best to use the correct spelling everywhere.

It may be best to start small. Maybe start with 3 cuts and have them sorted, so you can have a mental run-through before doing the complex stuffs

This looks to be the Cutting stock problem which is reducible to the Knapsack problem.  It is NP-hard.  Take a look at Cutting Stock Problem (C#) or How to find optimum combination for Cutting Stock Problem using Knapsack.

As others have said, if you debug it you will catch it. But this is what is happening. After you got your first CutGroup, for the second one, you have in your cuts list:
1. 3100, 2900, 1200......
you pick 3100, add to your cutGroup string, remove 3100 from cuts. Now Cuts is
2. 2900, 1200, ......
In the next iteration your i is 1, and so your code is picking 1200 not 2900

Its clear now :) thank you.
